# How do I link to a folder of plugins in Rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm converting a site to rails and have a line of code that I'm not sure how to convert to rails. It links to a folder that contains folders and plugins needed by the site.

`<script>var plugin_path = 'assets/plugins/';</script>`

I've tried using the `javascript_include_tag` but that only seems to work for single files.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I take it these plugins are just wads of third-party JS? Are you using Rails 6 or an older version of Rails? Older versions of Rails use something called Sprockets for managing the asset pipeline, while Rails 6 uses webpack by default. So, the answer depends on which you are using.

Comment: Its Rails 5, I'll look into sprockets thanks!

Comment: Check out the [asset pipeline guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization). It covers where to put the code so Sprockets can find it and how to use ``//= require`` to include it in your app's manifest.